# Is there any tree structure document which tells about how blender is structured?

Tags: interface, blend-files, outliner

there is any detailed tree structure on what comes under what?

What is accessible from where and what is not accessible?

A clear tree structure idea of blender data blocks, scene window hierarchy

Basically giving the logic of how blender is designed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the *Datablocks* view option in *Outliner*:

[image]

Comment: Its very cluttered and confusing, and has many

Comment: @ashwin It's cluttered and confusing as the rest of Blender, there is nothing better to view the blender structure than this. You can connect with developers and tell them what to improve. Please mark this answer as correct thanks.